# VB Deep Copy and Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

This is a console application which generates a times table with user input by asking the user to input rows and columns. I get two big errors in this code:

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Integer' 'because '1-dimensional array of Integer' is not derived from 'Integer'
```

and

```
'jaggedArrayArray' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

After some research online, I have come across two big concepts - Deep Copy and Shallow Copy - which I am still learning. I think that my main problem has to do with `Sub arrayPopulateJ`:

```
Sub arrayPopulateJ(ByVal jaggedArray() As Integer, ByVal columns As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim mult(columns) As Integer

    'Populates rows in jagged array
    For i = 0 To rows
        jaggedArray(i) = (i + 1)
    Next
    'Populates columns in arrays
    For i = 0 To rows
        For j = 0 To columns
            For k = 0 To columns
                mult(k) = (j + 1) * (k + 1)
            Next
        Next
        jaggedArray(i) = mult(columns)
    Next

End Sub
```

If you look at the line `jaggedArray(i) = mult(columns)` I think I am doing what is called a shallow copy and it is making this whole thing not work. What I want to happen is I want to be able to use `jaggedArray` as a 1D array and put 1D arrays into its elements (in my code that would be `mult(columns)`). I am still new to programming and VB and I am not sure how to do this. I thought that VB would be a high enough language that the flow of logic would work this way. But as I know now that is not the case. So what can I do to pass an whole array into a array and get this to work?

FULL CODE:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        'Declarations
        Dim awns As Char
        Dim switchOption As Integer
        Dim columns As Integer
        Dim rows As Integer
        Dim regularArray(,) As Integer = New Integer(,) {}
        Dim jaggedArray()() As Integer = New Integer(rows)() {}  'Problem here
        Dim topArray(columns) As Integer
        Dim sideArray(rows) As Integer
    'Starting Prompts
    Console.WriteLine("Hello this program will create a times table with")
    Console.WriteLine("user inputs in terms of rows and columns.")
    Console.WriteLine("Pick between these two options.")
    Console.WriteLine("Option 1: Times table with a regular array.")
    Console.WriteLine("Option 2: Times table with a jagged array.")

    Do
        Console.Write("Which option do you want? ")
        switchOption = Console.ReadLine

        Console.WriteLine("How many columns do you want? ")
        columns = Console.ReadLine
        columns = columns - 1
        Console.WriteLine("How many rows do you want? ")
        rows = Console.ReadLine
        rows = rows - 1
        Console.Write(vbNewLine)

        'ReDim's
        ReDim regularArray(columns, rows)
        ReDim jaggedArray(rows)
        ReDim topArray(columns)
        ReDim sideArray(rows)


        Select Case switchOption
            Case 1
                'Array populations 
                arrayPopulate(regularArray, columns, rows)
                singlePopulate(topArray, columns)
                singlePopulate(sideArray, rows)

                Dim i As Integer
                Dim j As Integer
                Console.Write("     ")
                For j = 0 To columns
                    Dim top As String = topArray(j)
                    Console.Write(top.PadLeft(3) + ": ")
                Next
                Console.Write(vbNewLine)
                For j = 0 To rows
                    Dim side As String = sideArray(j)
                    Console.Write(side.PadLeft(3) + ": ")
                    For i = 0 To columns

                        Dim num As String = regularArray(i, j)
                        Console.Write(num.PadLeft(3) + ": ")
                    Next
                    Console.Write(vbNewLine)
                Next

            Case 2
                'Array populations 
                arrayPopulateJ(jaggedArray, columns, rows)    'Problem here

                singlePopulate(topArray, columns)
                singlePopulate(sideArray, rows)
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim j As Integer
                Console.Write("     ")
                For j = 0 To columns
                    Dim top As String = topArray(j)
                    Console.Write(top.PadLeft(3) + ": ")
                Next
                Console.Write(vbNewLine)
                For j = 0 To rows
                    Dim side As String = sideArray(j)
                    Console.Write(side.PadLeft(3) + ": ")
                    Dim num As String = jaggedArrayArray(j) 'Problem here
                    Console.Write(num.PadLeft(3))
                    Console.Write(vbNewLine)
                Next

        End Select

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to run again y/n?")
        awns = Console.ReadLine()
    Loop Until awns = "n"
End Sub
Sub arrayPopulateJ(ByVal jaggedArray() As Integer, ByVal columns As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim mult(columns) As Integer
    ReDim mult(columns)

    'Populates rows in jagged array
    For i = 0 To rows
        jaggedArray(i) = (i + 1)
    Next

    'Populates columns in arrays
    For i = 0 To rows
        For j = 0 To columns
            For k = 0 To columns
                mult(k) = (j + 1) * (k + 1)
            Next
        Next
        jaggedArray(i) = mult(columns)
    Next

End Sub

Sub arrayPopulate(ByVal regularArray(,) As Integer, ByVal columns As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer)
    'Local Declarations
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim mult As Integer

    For i = 0 To rows
        For j = 0 To columns
            mult = (i + 1) * (j + 1)
            regularArray(j, i) = mult
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Sub singlePopulate(ByVal topArray() As Integer, ByRef count As Integer)
    'Local Declarations
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pop As Integer

    For i = 0 To count
        pop = (i + 1)
        topArray(i) = pop
    Next
End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "deep" or "shallow" copy issue here. That's a red herring.

Your first problem was that you had `jaggedArrayArray` in your code, but the variable was declared as `jaggedArray`.

The next problem that `arrayPopulateJ` was expecting the first parameter to be of type `Integer()` when it should have been `Integer()()`.

Fixing both of this it was then just an easy matter of writing `arrayPopulateJ` to be:

```
Sub arrayPopulateJ(ByVal jaggedArray()() As Integer, ByVal columns As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer)
    For i = 0 To rows
        Dim column(columns) As Integer
        jaggedArray(i) = column
        For j = 0 To columns
            jaggedArray(i)(j) = (i + 1) * (j + 1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I also cleaned up `arrayPopulate` to be:

```
Sub arrayPopulate(ByVal regularArray(,) As Integer, ByVal columns As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer)
    For i = 0 To rows
        For j = 0 To columns
            regularArray(j, i) = (i + 1) * (j + 1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I ran your code at that point and it worked.